# How to repeat a part of an RxJava chain when a condition is met?

Tags: java, rx-java2

I have four `Flowable<Boolean>`s, `task0`, `task1`, `task2` and `task3`. Now, `task2` might flip a flag, and if that flag becomes true, the chain should start from the beginning. Only if the flag is not set should `task3` be executed.

In pseudocode, it would be something like this:

```
boolean shouldRestart = false
do:
    shouldRestart = false
    execute task 0
    execute task 1
    execute task 2 <-- this might set shouldRestart to true
while shouldRestart == true
execute task 3
```

How does this translate to RxJava? I tried to simulate it like this:

```
AtomicBoolean b = new AtomicBoolean(true);
task0.concatWith(task1)
    .concatWith(task2)
    .repeatWhen(f -> f.flatMap(b -> {
        boolean a = b.getAndSet(false);
        return a ? Flowable.just(b) : Flowable.empty();
    }))
    .concatWith(task3)
    .subscribe(b -> System.out.println("b: " + b));
```

This does repeat the tasks 0, 1 and 2 correctly, but it also invokes the final observer and never executes the task 3:

```
Task 0
b: true
Task 1
b: true
Task 2
b: true
Task 0
b: true
Task 1
b: true
Task 2
b: true
```

The result I'm after is like this:

```
Task 0
Task 1
Task 2
Task 0
Task 1
Task 2
Task 3
b: true
```

How would I approach this?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out:

```
AtomicBoolean i = new AtomicBoolean(false);
Single<Boolean> chain = task0.concatWith(task1)
    .concatWith(task2)
    .repeatUntil(() -> i.getAndSet(true))
    .concatWith(task3)
    .lastOrError();

chain.subscribe(b -> System.out.println("b: " + b));
```

This will result in the wanted behavior:

```
Task 0
Task 1
Task 2
Task 0
Task 1
Task 2
Task 3
b: true
```